# Simple htaccess redirect - subdomain to folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect http://[random-string].domain.com/ to http://domain.com/folder/[random-string]/

I currently have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/folder/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

It currently points to http://domain.com/folder//. (The $1 is missing) How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis to grab the value matched, in your case:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/folder/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

assuming you also want to redirect http://[random-string].domain.com/something to http://domain.com/folder/[random-string]/something

Comment: Hm, the $1 variable is still missing. (It redirects to http://domain.com/folder//)

Comment: Ok my bad, see the edit to my answer (use % instead of $ for RewrtieCond)

Comment: Cheers! Works fine for me and the $1 bit is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

how i fix it?
my subdomain not is randomically 
have  where the replace for $1 ?
cheers

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/folder/%1/$1 [R=301,L]