# How can I link a subdomain to a joomla user?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, joomla2.5

We've got a custom component that does all sorts of wonderful things for a a registered user.  Among the requirements is the ability to use the username as a subdomain to retrieve and use a variety of their settings.  e.g. http://abc.ourdomain.com must retrieve the jos_users record with the username "abc".  From there we use that info in the session and carry on with component functions with those values.

I've tried tinkering with $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] to get things started, but am hoping that there is a cleaner approach with htaccess, or a plugin that would serve the purpose better.

Comment: I have never tried this before, but it should work with htaccess. I would try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322586/simple-htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-folder)

Comment: This looks promising...htaccess is voodoo to me, so whenever it's left to me to figure out what's to be done with it, I don't even know how to properly google it.  i think this is the starting point i need.  Thx.

Comment: I feel the same way. I thought I'd seen a similar situation to this before. Definitely want a way to use variables in my opinion so you don't have to set up each user. If you change "folder" to the name of your component, you could probably even set up something in your router.php file of the component to check just in case the subdomain doesn't exist, you could send them to something besides a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work in one .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.ourdomain\.com  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !getuser\.php  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  http://ourdomain.com/getuser.php?user=%1     [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://abc.ourdomain.com`

To:

`http://ourdomain.com/getuser.php?user=abc`

Captures the subdomain `abc` into group %1 and appends it as query to the script.

`abc`is a variable string.

`getuser.php` can be any script. The key `user` is an example, it can be any name too.

For permanent redirection, replace [L] with [R=301,L]

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Will tinker with it while I wait for enough time to pass to accept your answer.  Thanks so much, and most especially for not reprimanding me for not "showing what I've tried"  (How DO you put in a days worth of tinkering to meet that demand, lol)...